# How to enable all the radio button with a checkbox by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

I have 8 labels and each of them has 5 radio buttons(1-bad,2,3,4,5-good) and the user should select top 5.I have already figure out to disable rest of buttons when user already chosen 5 radio button here is the code,

```
                  1     2     3     4     5      
apple             o     o     o     o     o
banana            o     o
orange
onion
potato
grape
peach
cherry

<script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
        var l = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
        if( l >= 6 ) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            for(var i=0; i < $('input[type="radio"]').length; i++) {
                if( !$('input[type="radio"]').eq(i).is(':checked') ) {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').eq(i).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    });

if (document.getElementById('edit-submitted-enable-1').checked){

$("input[type=radio]").attr('enabled', true);
}


});




</script>
```

How ever, If the user would like to edit his choice there must be "enable all radio buttons" I am trying to enable all radio button on the page with a checkbox how ever the code didnt work

```
if (document.getElementById('edit-submitted-enable-1').checked){

$("input[type=radio]").attr('enabled', true);
}
```

Comment: it would be a bit of help if you could provide sample code of what checkbox and what radio buttons are you trying to work with?
Do you want to activate Radio Buttons with one checkbox??
Radio buttons are used when you have to choose 1 among many, if you want to select more than 1, you could always use Checkboxes.

Comment: I will edit my first message,sorry

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons have property called `checked`. You change use event handler on "enable all radio buttons", something like

```
  $('.enable-all-radios').on("click", function() {
     $("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", false)
  });
```